# Подключение Яндекс Электронная коммерция на Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, json, woocommerce, яндекс-метрика

Добрый день! Подключая ecommerce столкнулся с проблемой, данные не отправляются(
Сайт на WordPress плагин WooCommerce, яндекс счетчик обновил! Пытался сделать костыль когда на нажатие товара вылетала функция

```
$("[data-product-id=1311]").click(
dataLayer.push({
    "ecommerce": {
        "add": {
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": "1311",
                    "name": "CARKU E-Power-3",
                    "price": 4490,
                    "variant": "Черно-красный",
                    "category": "Аксессуар",
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  })
);
```

но все тщетно, зато когда вызываю функцию без переменной и метода клик данные отправляются! Ранее подключал еком на bitrix там через модули намного проще) Подскажите пожалуйста как это лучше сделать?

Еще также проблема, каждый раз создается новый объект ecommerce а не добавляются данные в объект products. И еще при переходе по сайту объект не сохраняется( Как сделать так чтобы он его запоминал? Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Смотря как подключить. Скорее всего, проблему решит `.on('click', function...`

Comment: Еще заметил проблему что объект dataLayer сбрасывается при переходе по сайту, как его можно сохранить чтобы данные в нем не терялись? скрипт работает из статичного footer'a

Comment: Данные при переходах между страницами сохраняют в cookie или local storage

Comment: @KAGGDesign а как это можно реализовать с объектом?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4225071/6817117